# Representing Relations in RESTful API

Tags: api, google-app-engine, restlet

I am designing a RESTful API, using RESTlet, for a set of resources that are related.

For instance:

A Person (/people/124) resource has a property "favoriteThing" that may be Car, Food, Toy.

Now lets say a user of the API would like to update this property by performing a POST to /person/124/favoriteThing URL.

However, to process this request I need to record this new relation in the Datastore (requires a Key(Kind, Id)).

So I have two troubling options:

1) Expect a URL in the body of the POST (this seems RESETful)
But how can I cleanly translate from URL to Datastore Key, requires (Kind, ID).

2) Expect (Kind,ID) in the body of the POST (Very easy)
But this allows something other than URL to serve as a resource identifier in the API

What is the most RESTful solution to this problem? 
Maybe something other than what I've considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm going to assume Python here because it's more concise)

POST to /person/124/favoriteThing with the 'thing' itself as a POST parameter seems correct to me.

So now your question is, how to implement that cleanly? Well, is the '124' in the URI above the key of the Person? You can encode a Key() into a string just by casting it, eg.

```
uri = '/person/%s' % str(person.key())
```

A nice trick is you can use regex grouping in your WSGIApplication constructor:

```
def main():
  application = WSGIApplication(['/people/(.*)', PersonHandler], debug=True)
```

Then when you get a POST to your PersonHandler, you can split the relevant path:

```
class PersonHandler(RequestHandler):
  def post(self, path):
    (key, property) = path.split('/')
    person = Person().get(Key(key))
    # check that property is valid, get POST param and change it
```

Comment: I am using Java with RESTlet framework. But the key idea is the same. So sounds like the correct solution is to come up with some sort of URI->Key mapping mechanism and never expose the ID of the fields outside of the API.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Moishe's response, you can actually define parts of the path as variables (at least in Python) rather than parsing the path.

So to process '.../person/124/favorite':

```
class PersonHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, person_key, favorite):        
        person = Person.get(db.get(person_key))
        person.Favorite = favorite
        person.put()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/person/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', PersonHandler)],
                                                                         debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```